# string input issue c++ using character array

Tags: c++

getting runtime error on codeforces 1167a
http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1167/A

string input issue

```
int n;
int temp=0;
cin>>n;
//n++;

while(n--)
{
    int nn;
    cin>>nn;
    //cout<<n<<endl;

    if(nn<11)
    {
        cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        continue;
    }

    char* str = new char[nn+1];
    cin>>str;

    for(int i=0;i<=(nn-11)+1;++i)
    {
        if(str[i]=='8')
        {
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
            temp=8;
            delete[] str;
            break;

        }




    }

    if(temp!=8)
    {
        cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }

    temp=0;

}
```

input

15
11
88888888888
100
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
100
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
100
1111111111111111111111111111811111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
100
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111181111111111
100
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...

output

YES
YES
NO
YES
YES
YES
YES
YES
NO

runtime error

Comment: `char str[nn+1];` is not legal C++. In C++ array sizes have to be *compile time constants*.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up.

There's two ways you could handle this, but you are doing half of one and half of the other.

You could use dynamic allocation

```
char* str = new char[nn+1];
...
delete[] str;
```

Or you could use a variable length array (VLA).

```
char str[nn+1];
...
```

Your code uses a VLA but then tries to `delete` it as if you are using dynamic allocation.

Of the two alternatives use dynamic allocation, VLAs are not legal C++, even though some compilers accept them.

A better C++ solution would be to use a `std::string`. Then the allocation will be handled for you.